# Defining set containing permutations of [n].

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, notation

Suppose I want to define set $S$ containing permutations of $[n]= \{1,2,3,...,n\}$, is the following true?
$$S := \{\:\{s_{i}\}_{i\in [n]}\mid (s_{i} \in [n])\:\land (s_{j}\not=s_{k},\:j<k)\}$$
or is there a better representation of set $S$.

Comment: The final $\le n$ is useless. Anyway, what for do you want such a formula? [A more readable and common definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) is: $S$ is the set of bijections from $[n]$ to $[n]$, but you may indeed replace here "bijections" by "injections" (or by "surjections").

Comment: Noted, it was just a random thought. I was having trouble looking for such definitions online and wonders if the definition I proposed is correct.

Comment: Personally, I would much rather see a definition worded similar to the wording in @AnneBauval's comment (which is straightforward) than a complicated formula that I have to scrutinize to decipher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A permutation of $[n]$ is a bijection $\sigma :[n] \to [n]$. There are various standard notations like

- Two-line notation:
  $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 &2 & \ldots &n \\ \sigma(1) & \sigma(2) & \ldots & \sigma(n) \end{pmatrix}$$
  Here $\sigma$ is written as a $(2 \times n)$-matrix. In the first row we find the elements $i \in [n]$, in the second line below $i$ the value $\sigma(i) \in [n]$.
- One-line notation:
  $$\begin{pmatrix}  \sigma(1) & \sigma(2) & \ldots & \sigma(n) \end{pmatrix}$$
  Here $\sigma$ is written as a $(1 \times n)$-matrix which is nothing else than a $n$-tuple of elements of $[n]$. To interpret it, it essential to note that the set $[n]$ has a natural order. At position $i$ of the $n$-tupel we find the value $\sigma(i)$.

Both notations establish a natural bijection between the sets $\mathfrak S_n$ of permutations of $[n]$ and the set of $n$-tuples $(s_i)_{i \in [n]} = (s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_n)$ with pairwise distinct entries from the set $[n]$. In other words, we can identify $\mathfrak S_n$ with
$$\mathfrak T_n =\{(s_i)_{i \in [n]} \mid s_i \in [n], s_i \ne s_j \text{ for } i \ne j  \} = \{(s_i)_{i \in [n]} \mid s_i \in [n], s_i \ne s_j \text{ for } i < j  \}.$$
This is almost the same as you suggest in your question, but unfortunately you write $\{ s_i\}$ instead $(s_i)$. This is inadequate because $\{ s_i\}$ is just a *set*. Since sets do not have an order, we have indeed $\{ s_i\} = [n]$.

The natural bijection $\beta : \mathfrak S_n \to \mathfrak T_n$ is of course given by
$$\beta(\sigma) = (\sigma(i)) .$$

A serious conceptual disadvantage of working with $\mathfrak T_n$ is that it does not have an obvious law of composition for its elements. In contrast, in $\mathfrak S_n$ we can obviously compose bijections $\sigma, \tau$ as usual by *function composition* $\sigma \circ  \tau$ given by $(\sigma \circ \tau)(i) = \sigma(\tau(i))$. It is then fairly easy to verify that $(\mathfrak S_n, \circ)$ is a group. Of course we can use the identification of  $\mathfrak T_n$ with $\mathfrak S_n$ via $\beta$ to define a composition $\circ$ for $n$-tuples by
$$(s_i) \circ (t_i) = \beta(\beta^{-1}((s_i)) \circ \beta^{-1}((t_i)) .$$
But the explicit formula for $(s_i) \circ (t_i)$ without invoking $\beta$ is not very transparent and makes it much harder to show that $(\mathfrak T_n, \circ)$ is a group.